# $a^{\phi (n) +1} \equiv a \pmod{\! n}; $ Carmichael generalization of Fermat & Euler theorems.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, totient-function

> I want to know a proof of an alternative form of Fermat-Euler's theorem
>   $$a^{\phi (n) +1} \equiv a \pmod n$$
>   when $a$ and $n$ are not relatively prime.

I searched some number theory books and a cryptography book and internet, but there were only proofs of the original theorem  $a^{\phi (n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ or in case n=pq which is used for RSA. So I would be very thankful if someone show me a proof or book I should read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the proof below shows, the claim is true $\!\iff\! n$ is squarefree (i.e. a product of *distinct* primes). A simple counterexample is given by $\,n=4,\,a=2.\,$ Since $\,a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{\! n}\,$ we can not have $\,a^e \equiv a \pmod{\! n}\,$ for *any* $\,e>1.\,$ In particular $\,a^{\phi(n) +1}=a^{2+1} \equiv 0\not\equiv a \pmod{\!n}$.

Below are some handy more general results.

**Theorem** $ $ [(Korselt's Carmichael Criterion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) $\ $ For  $\rm\:1 < e,n\in \Bbb N\:$ we have

$$\rm \forall\, a\in\Bbb Z\!:\ n\mid a^e\!-a\ \iff\  n\ \ is\ \  squarefree, \  and \ \ p\!-\!1\mid e\!-\!1\ \, for\  all \ primes\ \ p\mid n\qquad$$

**Proof** $\ (\Leftarrow)\  $ By unique prime factorization (or Euclid's Lemma), a squarefree natural divides another iff all its prime factors do, so we need only show $\rm\:p\:|\:a^{\large e}\!-\!a\:$ for each prime $\rm\:p\:|\:n.\:$ It's clear if $\rm\,p \mid a.\,$ Else $\rm\!\bmod p\!:\ a \not\equiv 0\,$  $\rm\overset{\rm Fermat}\Longrightarrow\,  \color{c00}{a^{\large\color{#0a0}{p-1}} \equiv 1}$ so $\rm\,\color{#c00}{a^{\large\color{#0a0}{e-1}}\equiv 1}\,$ by $\rm \,\color{#0a0}{p\!-\!1\mid e\!-\!1}\,$ and [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242). Thus $\rm\,a^{\large e}-a\equiv a(\color{#c00}{a^{\large\color{#0a0}{e-1}}-1})\equiv a(\color{#c00}0)\equiv 0$.

$(\Rightarrow)\ \ $ Given that $\rm\: n\mid a^e\!-\!a\:$ for all $\rm\:a\in\Bbb Z,\:$ we must show

$$\rm (1)\ \  n\,\ is\ squarefree,\quad  and\quad  (2)\ \  p\mid n\:\Rightarrow\: p\!-\!1\mid e\!-\!1$$

$(1)\ \ $ If $\rm\,n\,$ isn't squarefree then
$\rm\,1\neq a^2\!\mid n\mid a^e\!-\!a \Rightarrow\:  a^2\mid a\:\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$ $\rm\: (note\ \ e>1\: \Rightarrow\: a^2\mid a^e)$

$(2)\ \ $ Let $\rm\ a\ $ be a generator ("primitive root") of the [cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/290427/242) multiplicative group of $\rm\:\Bbb Z/p,\,$
i.e. $\rm\ a\ $ has order $\rm\:p\!-\!1.\:$ Now  $\rm\:p\mid n\mid a\,(a^{e-1}\!-\!1)\:$  but $\rm\:p\nmid a,\:$ thus $\rm\: a^{e-1}\!\equiv 1\,\ ( mod\ p),\:$ [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\rm\:e\!-\!1\:$ must be divisible by $\rm\:p\!-\!1,\:$
the order of $\rm\ a\,\ (mod\ p).\quad$  **QED**

**Corollary** $\rm\,\ n\mid a^e b - a b^f\ $ if $\,\rm n\:$ is squarefree, and prime $\rm\:p\:|\:n\:\Rightarrow\: p\!-\!1\:|\:e\!-\!1,\,f\!-\!1$

**Proof** $\ $ By the Theorem $\rm\bmod n\!:\,\ a^e\equiv a,\, b^f\equiv b\,$ so $\rm\,a^e b - ab^f\equiv ab-ab\equiv 0$

**Corollary'** $\ n\mid f(a^{e_1},b^{e_2}) - f(a^{e_3},b^{e_4})\,$  if $\,n\,$ is squarefree, and prime $\,p\:|\:n\:\Rightarrow\: p\!-\!1\:|\:e_i\!-\!1\,$ and $\,f(x,y)\in\Bbb Z[x,y],\,$ i.e. $\,f\,$ is a polynomial in $\,x,y\,$ with integer coefficients.

**Proof** $\ $ By the Theorem $\bmod n\!:\,\ a^{e_i}\equiv a,\, b^{e_i}\equiv b\,$ so $f(a^{e_i},b^{e_i}) \equiv f(a,b)\,$ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

The equivalent definitions of Carmichael numbers are the special case $\,e = n\,$ below.

**Theorem** $\ $  The following are equivalent for  integers  $\,n,e>1$.
$(1)_{\phantom{|_{|_.}}}\  n\mid a^e\ -\ a\ \ $ for all $\,a\in\Bbb Z^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!,\: $ and $\ (e\!-\!1,n)=1$
$(2)_{\phantom{|_{|_.}}}\ n\mid a^{e-1}\!-1\ $ for all $\,a\in\Bbb Z\,$ with $\, \color{#90f}{(a,n)=1}= (e\!-\!1,n)$
$(3)\ \ \ \:\! n\,$ is squarefree, $ $ prime $\,p\mid n\,\Rightarrow\,   \color{#0a0}{p\!-\!1\mid e\!-\!1},\ p\nmid e\!-\!1$

**Proof** $\ \ $ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3467742/242)

Comment: So my security book was wrong since in the book's theorem, it has no square free condition. I should have tested the case a=2 and n=4. Thank you Bill Dubuque.

Answer (score -1):

Although this is an old question, I realized that I had actually asked and answered this question myself in my undergraduate education. Although the proof is a bit rough around the edges, hopefully it provides enough of a different view than the currently accepted answer as to be useful to someone in the future.

---

Conjecture: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We shall prove that $n$ is square-free if and only if for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, $z^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod } n)$.

Proof: $(\Rightarrow)$  Proceeding with the forward direction, let $n$ be a square-free natural number. Thus, $n$ is of the form $n=p_1p_2...p_r.$ We will now proceed by induction on the number of prime factors of $n$.

Base Case: If $n$ has one prime factor, then $n=p$ for some prime $p$. Since
$$z^{\phi(p)+1}=z^{p-1+1}=z^p\equiv z\ (\text{mod }p)$$

the base case is true.

Inductive Step: Now, assume that for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, $z^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod }n)$. Define $n'=nq$ where $\gcd(n,q)=1$. Note that $q$ is to the first power since $n'$ must be square-free. It suffices to show that
$$z^{\phi(n')+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod }n)$$

and
$$z^{\phi(n')+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod }q)$$

in order to conclude
$$z^{\phi(n')+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod }n').$$

For $q$, note that for $z\not\equiv 0\ (\text{mod }q)$, we have
$$z^{\phi(n')+1}=z\cdot z^{\phi(n)\phi(q)}=z(z^{\phi(q)})^{\phi(n)}=z(z^{q-1})^{\phi(n)}\equiv z\cdot 1^{\phi(n)}=z\ (\text{mod }q).$$

If $z\equiv 0\ (\text{mod }q)$, then
$$z^{\phi(n')+1}\equiv 0\equiv z\ (\text{mod }q).$$

Either way, we can conclude
$$z^{\phi(n')+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod }q).$$

For $n$, we have
$$z^{\phi(n')+1}=z^{\phi(n)\phi(q)+1}$$
$$=z^{\phi(n)(q-1)+1}=z^{\phi(n)(q-2+1)+1}=z^{\phi(n)(q-2)+\phi(n)+1}=z^{\phi(n)(q-2)}z^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv z\cdot z^{\phi(n)(q-2)}\ (\text{mod }n)$$
$$=z^{\phi(n)(q-2)+1}=z^{\phi(n)(q-3+1)+1}=z^{\phi(n)(q-3)+\phi(n)+1}=z^{\phi(n)(q-3)}z^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv z\cdot z^{\phi(n)(q-3)}\ (\text{mod }n)$$
$$\vdots$$

Continuing this process for $q$ steps, we have
$$\vdots$$
$$=z^{\phi(n)(q-(q-2))+1}=z^{2\phi(n)+1}=z^{\phi(n)+\phi(n)+1}=z^{\phi(n)}z^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv z\cdot z^{\phi(n)}\ (\text{mod }n)$$
$$=z^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod }n)$$

We conclude
$$z^{\phi(n')+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod }n).$$

As stated above, since $\gcd(n,q)=1$, this implies
$$z^{\phi(n')+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod }n').$$

By the principle of mathematical induction, we can conclude that if $n$ is square-free, then for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, $z^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod }n).$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Proceeding with the reverse direction, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, we know
$$z^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv z\ (\text{mod }n).$$

Now, suppose by way of contradiction that $n$ is not square-free. From the canonical form of $n$,
$$n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}...p_r^{k_r},$$

this would imply that for $1\leq i\leq r$, there exists $k_i>1$. For ease of notation, define such an exponent and prime as $k_i=t$ and $p_i=q$ respectively. Also, define $n'=\frac{n}{q^t}$. From our initial condition, choose $z=q$. Thus
$$q^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv q\ (\text{mod }n).$$

This implies there exists $N$ such that
$$nN=q^{\phi(n)+1}-q$$
$$q^tn'N=q^{\phi(n)+1}-q$$
$$q^{t-1}n'N=q^{\phi(n)}-1.$$

However, since $t>1$, this implies
$$0\equiv q^{t-1}n'N_1 =q^{\phi(n)}-1\equiv -1\ (\text{mod }q),$$

a contradiction. We conclude $n$ is square-free. QED