# How can I demonstrate that $x-x^9$ is divisible by 30?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility

How can I demonstrate that $x-x^9$ is divisible by $30$ whenever $x$ is an integer?

I know that $$x-x^9=x(1-x^8)=x(1-x^4)(1+x^4)=x(1-x^2)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)$$

but I don't know how to demonstrate that this number is divisible by $30$.

Comment: do primes $2,3,5$ one at a time

Comment: **Hint:** Factor it.

Comment: I don't know how to factor it

Comment: @user112127 how do you not know? You wrote it factored when you said $x-x^9 = x(1-x^2)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)$

Comment: Ok. So x−x^9=x(1-x)(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)

Comment: and (1-x)x(1+x) is divisible by 3 . Am i right ?

Comment: @user112127 that depends. Are you assuming $x$ is an integer? Or can it be any number?

Comment: @ graydad   x is integer.

Comment: and x(x+1) is dibisible by 2 . Now we have to prove that the number is divisible by 5

Comment: @user112127 The product of three successive integers is divisible by $3!=6$: proof $\binom n3 = n(n-1)(n-2)/6$ is an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's factor $x^9-x$ like you have done:
$$
x^9-x=(x-1)x(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1).\tag{$*$}
$$
Let's look at the RHS. The product of the first 2 terms is divisible by $2$ because it consists of 2 consecutive integers. Similarly, the product of the first 3 terms is divisible by $3$. Now, if you had
$$
(x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)(x+2)
$$
then of course that would be divisible by $5$ as well. But note this
$$
(x-1)x(x+1)(x^2+1)-(x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)(x+2)=5x(x^2-1)\equiv 0\pmod{5}.
$$
So the product of the first 4 terms of the RHS of ($*$) is also divisible by $5$. Now you're done.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. The divisibility by $5$ trick above comes from noticing $x^2+1=5+(x^2-4)=5+(x-2)(x+2)$.

Comment: do yo mean 5 + (x^2-4)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, typo. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6):

You have to prove that $x-x^9$ is divisible by $2$, $3$ and $5$.

1. $x\equiv x^9\pmod{2}$ is obvious, isn't it?
2. By Fermat's little theorem, $x^3\equiv x\pmod{3}$, so $x^9=(x^3)^3\equiv x^3\equiv x\pmod{3}$
3. By Fermat's little theorem, $x^5\equiv x\pmod{5}$, so $x^9=x^4x^5\equiv x^4 x\equiv x^5\equiv x\pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a special case of the following theorem. The direction we need $(\Leftarrow)$ 
has a [very simple proof.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/786547/242)

**Theorem** $\ $  For natural numbers $\rm\:a,e,n\:$ with $\rm\:e,n>1$

$\qquad\rm n\:|\:a^e-a\:$ for all $\rm\:a\:\iff  n\:$ is squarefree, and prime $\rm\:p\:|\:n\:\Rightarrow\: p\!-\!1\:|\:e\!-\!1$