# Prime Repunit Numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, repunit-numbers

proof that if a repunit number is prime **n has to be prime**

So a repunit number is a number that it's all digits are 1. For example $R_{2} = 11$ $R_{7} = 1111111$ and so on. Repunit numbers can be represented as $\frac{10^{n} -1}{9}$ in general.

Problem is asking if $\frac{10^{n} -1}{9}$ is prime then $n$ has to be prime. İts easy to see for $n=3k \:\:(k \in \mathbb{Z})$ it is divisible by $3$ and for $n=2m \:\:(m \in \mathbb{Z})$ it is divisible by $11$

But ı stumbled upon how to prove that $n$ is prime

Comment: I don't think so :( I am new at stack exchange and my English isn't well yet so ı don't understand some of that page says but from my understanding, it is not the answer to this

Comment: Please explain how that question differs from yours.

Comment: oh ı see it now sorry I didn't see it when I look at it first thank you for your answer

Comment: No problem.  Good luck!

Comment: For your recent [deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4191168/242) you should see [Carmichael numbers,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number)  e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/786547/242)

Comment: How can ı study such special numbers like this ? What should i pre learn in order to study these consepts ? I only know very elementsry number theory right now what are your suggestions for me