# RSA: what is $k$ in the formula to calculate $d$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function, multiplicative-function

In RSA, to calculate $d$, when given $\phi(n)$ and $e$, I stumbled upon this formula:

$$d = \dfrac{k \phi(n) + 1}{e}$$

But what does $k$ stand for? How to obtain the value for $k$?

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: First place to look is the same place you stumbled upon that formula.

Comment: [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54348/242) the decryption exponent $\,d\,$ is chosen so that $\!\bmod{\!\phi(n)}\!:\ d\equiv 1/e,\,$ i.e. $\,de \equiv 1,\,$ i.e. $\,(de\!-\!1)/\phi(n)\,$ is an integer, denoted $\,k\,$ here.

Answer (score 2):

$d$ in an integer which satisfies

$ed\equiv 1\mod \phi(n)$,

which means that there exists an integer $k$ such that

$ed = 1 + k\cdot \phi(n).$

Answer (score 1):

We can rearrange your equation to obtain:

$$de = k\phi(n)+1$$

or:

$$de \equiv 1 \pmod {\phi(n)}$$

Therefore $d$ is the *inverse* of $e$ in $\mathbb Z_{\phi(n)}$. (This only makes sense if $e$ and $\phi(n)$ are coprime, by Bezout's Lemma.)

To find this $d$ (and the less important $k$), we can use the Euclidean Algorithm.